# Keeping UI of Layout also on Page Refresh in Next.js / React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I would like to keep the state of the layout UI also on a full-page refresh. With next persistent Layout, I can keep it persistent with Link changes but I don't know how to achieve this for a full-page reload.

Maybe saving some state in local storage , PWA or some kind of SSR CSR could achieve this but I can't find what here would be best practice.

layout.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Confirmer from '../common/Confirmer';
import Notifier from '../common/Notifier';

import { Store } from '../../lib/store';
import ArrowDropDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowDropDown';
import HelpOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HelpOutline';
import DashboardIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Dashboard';
import PersonAddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/PersonAdd';
import styles from './layout.module.scss';
import MenuWithLinks from 'components/common/MenuWithActions';
import SimpleButton from '../common/SimpleButton';
import SearchBar from '../common/SearchBar';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

import Router from 'next/router';
import MenuWithActions from 'components/common/MenuWithActions';
import { useTeamSelector, useUserSelector } from '../../lib/store/redux_store/store';

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const URL_APP = dev ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_APP : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION_URL_APP;

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  store?: Store;
  isMobile?: boolean;
  firstGridItem?: boolean;
  teamRequired?: boolean;
};

function Layout({ children }: Props) {
  const currentUserRedux = useUserSelector();
  const currentTeamRedux = useTeamSelector();

  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleDrawer = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('toggleDrawer');
    setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen);
  };

  if (!currentUserRedux._id) {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container__logout}>
        <div className={styles.head}>
          <div className={styles.logo}>
            <img src="/Logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.main}>{children}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <div className={styles.head}>
          <div className={styles.head__menuToggle} onClick={toggleDrawer}>
            {drawerOpen ? <CloseIcon /> : <MenuIcon />}

            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.head__team__menu}>
            <MenuWithActions
              options={currentUserRedux.teams.map((team) => {
                return {
                  text: team.name,
                  action: () => Router.push(`/teams/${team.slug}/discussions`),
                };
              })}
            >
              <SimpleButton name={currentTeamRedux.name} outlined={false} color="#95E1D3">
                <ArrowDropDownIcon
                  color="inherit"
                  style={{
                    verticalAlign: 'super',
                  }}
                />
              </SimpleButton>
            </MenuWithActions>
          </div>

          <div
            onClick={() => Router.push(`${URL_APP}/workflows`)}
            className={styles.head__dashboard}
          >
            <DashboardIcon />
            <div>Dashboard</div>
          </div>

          <MenuWithLinks
            options={[
              {
                text: 'Help Center',
                action: () => console.log('Go to Help Center'),
              },
              {
                text: 'Contact Support',
                action: () => console.log('Open Support Modal'),
              },
              {
                text: 'Whats New',
                action: () => console.log('Show whats new Site'),
              },
              {
                text: 'Plans and Pricing',
                action: () => console.log('Show Plans Page'),
              },
              {
                text: 'Contact Sales',
                action: () => console.log('Open Sales Modal or Site'),
              },
            ]}
          >
            <div className={styles.head__help}>
              <HelpOutlineIcon />
              <div className={styles.head__help__text}>Help</div>
            </div>
          </MenuWithLinks>

          <SearchBar />
          <SimpleButton name="Invite" color="#95E1D3">
            <PersonAddIcon />
          </SimpleButton>
          {/*<Button color="#95E1D3" variant="contained" endIcon={<PersonAddIcon />}>*/}
          {/*  Invite*/}
          {/*</Button>*/}
          <div>
            <MenuWithActions
              options={[
                {
                  text: 'Your Settings',
                  action: () =>
                    Router.push(
                      `/your-settings?teamSlug=${currentTeamRedux.slug}`,
                      `/teams/${currentTeamRedux.slug}/your-settings`,
                    ),
                  highlighterSlug: '/your-settings',
                },
                {
                  text: 'Team Settings',
                  action: () =>
                    Router.push(
                      `/team-settings?teamSlug=${currentTeamRedux.slug}`,
                      `/teams/${currentTeamRedux.slug}/team-settings`,
                    ),

                  highlighterSlug: '/team-settings',
                },
                {
                  text: 'Billing',
                  action: () =>
                    Router.push(
                      `/billing?teamSlug=${currentTeamRedux.slug}`,
                      `/teams/${currentTeamRedux.slug}/billing`,
                    ),
                  highlighterSlug: '/billing',
                },
                {
                  separator: true,
                },
                {
                  text: 'Log out',

                  action: () =>
                    Router.push(
                      `${
                        dev
                          ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_API
                          : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION_URL_API
                      }/logout`,
                      `${
                        dev
                          ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_API
                          : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION_URL_API
                      }/logout`,
                    ),
                  externalServer: true,
                },
              ]}
            >
              <div className={styles.head__menu}>
                <img
                  className={styles.head__menu__image}
                  src={currentUserRedux.avatarUrl}
                  alt="Add username here later in the book"
                />

                <ArrowDropDownIcon color="action" className={styles.head__menu__icon} />
              </div>
            </MenuWithActions>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`${styles.sideDrawer} ${drawerOpen ? styles.sideDrawerVisible : ''}`}>
          <div className={styles.side}>
            <div className={styles.logo}>
              <img src="/Logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
            </div>
            <div>Link 1</div>
            <div>Link 2</div>
            <div>Link 3</div>
            {/*<DiscussionList store={store} team={store.currentTeam} />*/}
          </div>
        </div>
        )<div className={styles.main}>{children}</div>
      </div>
      <div
        className={`${styles.backdrop} ${drawerOpen ? styles.backdropVisible : ''}`}
        onClick={toggleDrawer}
      ></div>
      <Notifier />

      <Confirmer />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

_app.tsx

```
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';

import { getUser} from '../lib/api/public';
import { getInitialData } from '../lib/api/team-member';

import { initializeStore, Store } from '../lib/store';
import { reduxStore } from '../lib/store/redux_store/store';
import './_base.scss';

// import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { AuthProvider } from '../lib/AuthContext';
import { setCurrentUser, setTeams } from 'lib/store/redux_store/slices/userSlice';
import { setCurrentTeam } from '../lib/store/redux_store/thunks/teamThunks';

// add models
type Props = {
  Component: NextPage;
  pageProps: any;
  initialState: any;
};

function App({ Component, pageProps }: Props) {
  const store: Store = initializeStore({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchInitialData = async () => {
      console.log('Useffect in _app.tsx called');
      try {
        const response = await getUser();
        const userData = response.user;
        reduxStore.dispatch(setCurrentUser(userData));
        if (userData) {
          const initialData = await getInitialData({
            data: { teamSlug: userData.defaultTeamSlug },
          });
          const teams = initialData.teams;

          reduxStore.dispatch(setTeams(teams));
          const team = teams && teams.find((t) => t.slug === userData.defaultTeamSlug);
          reduxStore.dispatch(setCurrentTeam(team));
          if (team._id && userData._id) {
            setLoading(false);
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
    fetchInitialData();
  }, []);

  const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';
  if (loading) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href={isServer ? '/fonts/server.css' : '/fonts/cdn.css'} />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
        </Head>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Provider store={reduxStore}>
          <AuthProvider>
            <Component {...pageProps} store={store} />
          </AuthProvider>
        </Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```